# How to count the number of requests over a specific period of time

Tags: prometheus, promql

When an http request comes in, metrics with method and status code as labels are accumulated in `Prometheus`. I am trying to create a chart for a specific period by receiving data from `Prometheus` on a web made with `React`. I want to make it like the example below.

[image]

The x-axis is the period, and the y-axis is the request count for that date.
I created it using increase() as follows, but the expected value does not come out.

```
increase(osori_requests_total[10d])
```

I want to express data accumulated over 10 days by marking 10 dots per day, how do I collect the data?
And if a specific date is specified, how do I enter the range?

Answer (score 1):

You should think of query as what data should be represented at every point of graph, and since you expect increase over last day, you should use query

```
increase(osori_requests_total[1d])
```

Regarding "10 days, 10 points" refer to [official documentation for API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries):

> - `start=<rfc3339 | unix_timestamp>`: Start timestamp, inclusive.
> - `end=<rfc3339 | unix_timestamp>`: End timestamp, inclusive.
> - `step=<duration | float>`: Query resolution step width in duration format or float number of seconds.

So your parameters, should look something like this
`start=1702409030&end=1702412630&step=1d` or this
`start=2023-12-12T23:00:00.000Z&end=2023-12-02T23:00:00.000Z&step=1d`

---

On related note, please be aware of `increase` function behaviour noted in [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase):

> The increase is extrapolated to cover the full time range as specified in the range vector selector, so that it is possible to get a non-integer result even if a counter increases only by integer increments.

Comment: I tried ```query=increase%28http_requests_total%5B1d%5D%29&start=1701549762&end=1702413762&step=1d```. However, the resulting value is larger than the count I requested (even as a decimal point). Since there was only a request for two days, I received a total of two vector values ​​and went as follows.
"values":[[1702327362,"2.0013956734124214"],[1702413762,"62.01418148809371"] (A total of 37 requests were made over two days)

Comment: @yjlee, this is outside of the scope of this question. I recall Prometheus producing bigger than expected values (something like 12.2 instead of 10), but I don't know if more than x2 of expected is that kind of case. Only thing I can suggest is to check your raw metric value.